# PublishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes not including newly added items

Tags: navigation, spnavigationnode

I am trying to get the collection of all the items of left menu programmatically.

When any new publishing page is added, it shows in OOTB left navigation, but when I try to get navigation nodes programmatically using "PublishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNode" this does not include newly added publishing page.

If I go to Site Settings >> Navigation, and show/hide any node and click "OK", then "PublishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNode" starts including newly added page as well.

I need to do this programmatically, how to get newly added page included in "PublishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNode" without performing show/hide manually from Site Settings | Navigation.

Any advice how to get this worked will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ys. one of my  friend had also wasted a whole day just to get newly added page in navigation collection. but no luck.
My suggestion is try to use sitemapdatasource for that. may be it can help you.